# In Android EditText , replace previous latest word in editText on press space bar

Tags: java, android

I am developing an translator app and in this app if the user enter the word and press space bar then it will just act like an auto correct the previous latest word in edit text . how to manage this onTextchanged() and any other technique for this help me

Answer (score 2):

All you need is [autoCompleteTextView](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_autocompletetextview_control.htm) and [sharePrefrences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to know which words were used